# Remove all CSS Stylesheets from a page

Tags: jquery, css

I want to show a page without any css applied. Is it somehow possible to add a jquery switch inside the page to disable all stylesheets?

Reason: I want to show a client the importance of Design by giving him the opportunity to disable the css styles of his site. It is way more convincing when he can trigger it on his own :)

Comment: What might be the practical purpose? Testing, perhaps, but testers could be expected to know how to use browser tools for such purposes. Even IE has a tool for disabling author style sheets these days.

Comment: check my answer and mark it as answer because it works with any stylesheet ibncluding embedded ones: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118005/236062

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want it to fire after a click:

```
$(".element").click(function(){
    $("link[rel='stylesheet']").remove();
});
```

or at the beginning:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("link[rel='stylesheet']").remove();
 });
```

Comment: Thanks guys. I wanted to show a client the importance of Design by giving him the opportunity to disable the css styles of his site. It is way more convincing when he can trigger it on his own :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$('link[rel="stylesheet"]').remove();
```

This will remove all stylesheets (all the styles applies due to those stylesheets) from the page.

Comment: It will not remove embedded style sheets (in `style` elements or in `style` attributes), or user style sheets, or browser default style sheets,

Comment: Or if you wanna go Vanilla, `for (var each of document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"]')){ each.remove(); }`

Answer (score 2):

Just spent few mintues to draft one

```
 (function(f,a,s,x){
  x=$(a);x.map(function(i,o){o=$(o);o.data(s+s,o.attr(s));o.removeAttr(s)});
  $(s+',link[rel='+s+'sheet]').appendTo(f);
  setTimeout(function(){
   $(a,f).appendTo('head');
   x.map(function(i,o){o=$(o);o.attr(s,o.data(s+s))})
  },999);
 })($('<i>'),'*','style');
```

Comment: my answer is cleaner than this mess :D

Answer (score 1):

Disable all

```
StyleSheetList.prototype.forEach=Array.prototype.forEach; // *Note
document.styleSheets.forEach((ss)=>ss.disabled=true);
```

or (Disable All)

```
for(styleSheet of document.styleSheets){ styleSheet.disabled=true; }
```

or (Remove all)

```
StyleSheetList.prototype.forEach=Array.prototype.forEach;
document.styleSheets.forEach((ss)=>ss.ownerNode.parentNode.removeChild(ss.ownerNode));
```

or (Remove all)

```
for(styleSheet of document.styleSheets){ styleSheet.ownerNode.parentNode.removeChild(styleSheet.ownerNode); }
```

***Note**:
If you don't want to change the prototype, you can invoke it like this:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.apply(document.styleSheets,[(ss)=>ss.disabled=true])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('link[rel="stylesheet"]').remove();
```

Comment: Any diference with the @techfoobar answer?

Comment: it does not work if the stylesheet is in the document itself (<style></style>)

Answer (score 0):

Place this on document ready:

```
$('link[rel=stylesheet]').remove();
```

Or bind it to a button.

Comment: it does not work if the stylesheet is in the document itself (<style></style>)

Answer (score 0):

A rough, dirty and brute approach:

```
document.querySelector("head").remove();
```

A bookmarklet version of the same code that you can paste as the URL of a bookmark.

You can also paste it into the address bar (for security reasons, when you paste the text, chrome/firefox remove the `javascript:` bit at the beginning so you'll need to type that by hand):

```
javascript:(function(){document.querySelector("head").remove();})()
```

Comment: this removes everything in <head> and not only stylesheets.

Comment: That's the exact reason why i marked this approach as brute and dirty.

Comment: @Zibri: if you need more fine-grained control then right-click the page (in chrome/Firefox) pick Inspect, locate in the header section the tag(s) that load the CSS files, right-click the tags and pick Remove.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to remove all kinds of styles, inline, internal, external.

```css
let elements=document.querySelectorAll("*");
elements.forEach(el=>{
    if(el.tagName==="LINK" || el.tagName==="STYLE") el.remove();
    else el.removeAttribute("style");
});
```

Thank me later! ;)